# Magnetic flux and the charge passing through a wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's Law we have
$$\mathcal{E}= -N\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}.$$
Assuming the flux only depends on time and can be expressed as $\Phi = \Phi (t)$, the aforesaid formula can be re-written as:
$$\mathcal{E}= -N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$
Therefore, assuming the wire is an Ohmian resistor, we have:
$$I = \frac{\mathcal{E}}{R} \Rightarrow I = -\frac{N}{R}\frac{d\Phi}{dt} \Rightarrow dq = -\frac{N}{R}d\Phi \Rightarrow \frac{d\Phi}{dq} = -\frac{R}{N}.$$
Therefore:
$$\Phi (t) = -\frac{R}{N} q(t) + C.$$
Is this equation plausible and true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this equation is correct, with the understanding that $q(t)$ is the total charge (up to an additive constant) that has flown through the resistor until time $t$.